# Pasar datos de un GridView que contiene comillas a una función en javascript

Tags: html, asp.net

Les agradecería si alguien me puede indicar cómo pasar los datos de una fila en particular de un GridView a una función javascript. Los datos se recuperan de una base de datos. Uno de los campos contiene comillas, por ejemplo:

```
.. Monitor color 24" ..
```

Esto genera un error al momento de querer ejecutar la función. El TemplateField está  programado de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
 <a href="#" onclick='productosOD("<%# Eval("codigoPD")%>",
                                  "<%# Eval("nombrePD")%>",
                                  "<%# Eval("preUnitario")%>")'
      title="Otros Datos">
      <img src="images/button_ok.png"
      alt="Otros Datos"
      border="0"
      class="wIMG12" />
</a>
```

Comment: ¿qué error te genera o cuál es el comportamiento cuando hay comillas?

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado asignarle al `nombrePD` el signo `\` antes de las comillas dobles?
Es decir: `.. Monitor color 24\" ..` ??

El back-slash (`\`) permite interpretar las comillas dobles como parte del texto